# Server side rendering for Flutter

Tags: flutter, seo, server-side-rendering

Is there a way to implement SSR in the flutter app to improve the SEO of the site?

Comment: Everything is possible. Learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an open issue in flutter github repo
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47600#issuecomment-569292377

as i understand there is no plans to support flutter web server side rendering  as flutters design was aimed to be client side